# Flex Builder SDK

Tags: apache-flex, sdk, builder

for a current project I have to work with Adobe Flex Builder 3, but need to change the used SDK. My problem is, that I don't even get the chance to do so. As you can see in the picture below there are no further options where there should be. Does anyone know this problem or is there a clue on how to solve it?

http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/2869/8v99rg8y_jpg.htm

Greetz
MD

Comment: That looks like a broken FlexBuilder (perhaps some conflicting plugins?). I'd say: reinstall it.

Comment: I agree with @RIAstar - you won't change anything in the workspace, so why hang on to a botched installation?

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Was what I thought too, but it didn't help. Will try it again though. Might it be due to my use of a 64-bit systems (path locating problems or something?)

Comment: Just in case other people have the same problem: It's been due to my java 64-bit installation and works now that I have deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have SDKs installed under

> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks

Comment: Hi, I do have all sdk folders in there.